# Fission is to Cyclotrons as Fusion is to _________?

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion, accelerator-physics

Using a cyclotron we can trigger fission in a controlled way.

My question is similar to cyclotrons, do we have a mechanism in which we can trigger fusion from a physics (non-chemistry) perspective that is in common use today?

I did come across: https://spectrum.ieee.org/5-big-ideas-for-making-fusion-power-a-reality#toggle-gdpr which looks to have several items or ideas, however I'm curious if there is anything that is a leader or more common, that may have documented results of what was able to be accomplished with the devices.

Comment: One can also do fusion reactions with various accelerators, so I'm unclear what you are asking here. One easy example is D-T fusion using a deuterium ion beam irradiating a tritium target - you only need a bit over 100kV.

Comment: @JonCuster, the above is very useful. Is the above process also achieved by using cyclotrons? If so, there was a gap in my understanding of cyclotrons.

Comment: Cyclotrons are just one apparatus to accelerate ions. 100kV is a bit on the low end - a standard Cockroft-Walton type power supply does just fine. But there are plenty of higher energy fusion reactions where a cyclotron would be useful. Don't focus on the particular machine, look to the cross section vs energy for the reaction of interest.

Comment: Super useful, thank you so much, you've given me plenty more to google. :)

Answer (score 0):

Arguably the most used, studied and successful device for fusion is called the [tokamak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokamak). Another more advanced reactor type is the [stellarator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellarator) while early fusion research focused on various types of [pinches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinch_(plasma_physics)) (particularly the [Z-pinch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-pinch), which you could still use to study plasmas and fusion in a controlled way.

EDIT: note that cyclotrons are also actively used in fusion to heat the fuel (see e.g. [electron cyclotron resonance heating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokamak#Radio-frequency_heating)).

Answer (score 0):

The [fusor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusor) is a relatively straightforward accelerator type device that allows fusion reactions to occur in a laboratory setting. It uses an electrostatic field generated by a grid to confine ions. The ions lose energy too rapidly in collisions with the grid to derive net power from such a device, however.

Answer (score 0):

> Fission is to Cyclotrons as Fusion is to?

[Cockroft-Walton accelerators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockcroft%E2%80%93Walton_generator) were used to demonstrate both fission and fusion before the cyclotron was widely known.

These experiments were performed in Rutherford's [Cavendish Lab at Cambridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavendish_Laboratory) in the late 1920s and early 1930s. Fusion was demonstrated by [Mark Oliphant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Oliphant) in 1932 after the team was given a small sample of heavy water and used the deuterons from it in the accelerator. This was the same year the cyclotron was made widely known via it's patent.

Most of what we know of the cross-sections of fusion reactions comes from updated versions of this sort of experiment, known as a [beam-target system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colliding_beam_fusion).